# how to formulate this constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra

Assume I want to solve a regression problem $AX=B$ , the matrix A is a thin matrix and rank deficient i.e, the nullity of $A$ is non-empty , i want a solution for which the block entries of $x$ are in decreasing magnitude ,
if $x = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}\\
{{x_2}}\\
 \vdots 
\end{array}} \right]$
i.e,${\left\| {{x_1}} \right\|_F} \ge {\left\| {{x_2}} \right\|_F} \cdots $
how can this be done , originally i was thinking of an optimization problem and a constraint doing that, any help will be appreciated